# Bash: Format environment variables in string

Tags: bash, curl, environment-variables, string-formatting

How does one format a string leveraging an environment variable within at the command line? For example, I want to curl and pass some variable, i.e.:

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"text": "I want to print an environment variable here, eg a path: $PATH"}' https://someapi.com/
```

Comment: If your intent is to have the result be valid JSON, that's probably not the right way to go about it -- you'll want to use a format-aware tool, or else surprising PATH values could result in invalid contents (at best), or injection attacks on your payload (at worst).

Comment: Not actually using the path variable, just an example. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easy answer is to change the kind of quotes you're using:

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode \
  'payload={"text": "I want to print an environment variable here, eg a path: '"$PATH"'"}' \
   https://someapi.com/
```

Notably, this is still using single-quotes on the outside (so you don't need to change your payload), but then it *ends* the single quotes, *starts* double quotes, and embeds your substitution in those double quotes (before ending them and switching back to single quotes, within which literal -- rather than syntactic -- double quotes can be embedded).

A variant on this approach, which avoids the need for syntactic quotes mixed into the document content, is to used an unquoted heredoc, [as advised by @chepner in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38135342/bash-format-environment-variables-in-string#comment63701876_38135374):

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode @- https://someapi.com/ <<EOF
payload={"text": "I want to print an environment variable here, eg a path: $PATH"}
EOF
```

---

The *better* answer is to use a tool that knows how to format JSON; [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is a widely popular choice. Consider the following example:

```
text="I want to print an environment variable here, eg a path: \"$PATH\""
curl -X POST --data-urlencode @- https://someapi.com/ <<EOF
payload=$(printf '%s\n' "$text" | jq -R '{text: .}')
EOF
```

This way you're guaranteed valid output, even if your environment variable contains backslashes, literal quotes, nonprintable characters, or whatever else may come.

Comment: Removed my answer, as @Charles has covered all the bases here. The observation that JSON requires `"` double quotes is an important one.

Comment: You can also read the data from standard input with `--data-urlencode @-`.

Comment: Also, the `-R` option can simplify the `jq` command to `echo "$text" | jq -R '{text: .}' | curl -X POST --date-urlencode @- https://someapi.com`.

Comment: Feel free. I did forget about the `payload=` prefix, so maybe `@-` isn't quite applicable here.